# Android Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing small android application in which I have 3 activities say A1, A2, A3. I can come back from A2 to A1 but when I start A3 and then if user clicks back button then I want to close all previous windows. I tried this in following ways:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

but this is not working for me. I am using action-bar activity.I tried to clear task :

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Above clearing task working for me but it start my A3 with some blank white screen.

Comment: where are you testing it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: clear task working for me. Only thing is that it start activity with white screen at start. Is that correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for all activities in the manifest? Also, declare it to `MainActivity`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" ... />
```

Usually, this behaviour happened when we do not declare a `launchMode` in the manifest. Although you are using `Intent.[MODE]`, then you will need this attribute. See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more information about `launchMode`.